# Why are metals generally cooler compared to their surrounding?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

I have felt sometimes that steel boxes or steel utensils are cooler than rest of the non-metal things when touched. Is it because it is a good conductor and our hands being at a higher temperature loose heat to it hence if we feel its cooler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is just as you explained.